# The framework needs the following extension(s) installed and loaded: GD

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

Im code in codeigniter 4 and wanna run this code:

```
$image = \Config\Services::image();
$image->withFile("./gambar/image.jfif");
$image->fit("200", "200", "center");
$image->save("./gambar/small_image.jfif");
```

But the following error is appear:

CodeIgniter\Images\Exceptions\ImageException
The framework needs the following extension(s) installed and loaded: GD.

How can i solve this?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/image.installation.php

Answer (score -2):

go to php.init

```
;extension=gd
to 
extension=gd
```

thats it :-)